# Salesforce Unauthenticated REST - HTTP 301

Tags: rest-api, rest, apexrest

I followed this tutorial, http://www.wadewegner.com/2013/03/creating-anonymous-rest-apis-with-salesforce-com/ , to create a public rest service in a developer sandbox. If I run any of the following:

```
curl GET http://sitedomainname.cs1.force.com/services/apexrest/Widgets/
curl POST http://sitedomainname.cs1.force.com/services/apexrest/Widgets/
curl PUT http://sitedomainname.cs1.force.com/services/apexrest/Widgets/
curl DELETE http://sitedomainname.cs1.force.com/services/apexrest/Widgets/
```

I get an HTTP 301 response.

But strangely, if I run that URL through POSTMAN, any request calls my GET method. And if I run it through SOAP UI, it calls my POST and GET methods correctly.

Finally, if I call the same url, but HTTPS, I get a HTTP 503 error.

Here is my class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Widgets/*')
global class WidgetController {

    @HttpGet
    global static String getWidgets() {
        return 'GET';
    }

    @HttpPost 
    global static String createNewWidget() {
        return 'POST';
    }

    @HttpDelete
    global static String deleteWidgetById() {
        return 'DELETE';
    }

    @HttpPut
    global static String updateWidget() {
        return 'PUT';
    }
}
```

I should also add that all of these methods work correctly when authenticated through workbench.

I have tried this in other sandboxes/editions and I have varying results. Are there any limitations with using this method? Like does it only work in Production and Developer editions?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a solution to this per se, but I have identified it is an issue with the particular sandbox in which I was testing the code. Generating a new sandbox and running the same code worked just fine. I'm not sure what settings could've caused the discrepancy (if any). We previously had Salesforce run a fixer on that sandbox because of a separate issue, so maybe there were still some underlying issues that occurred during the provisioning.